# Tag for differential equations

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

At the moment, we have tags [ode](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ode) and [difference-equations](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference-equations). Unfortunately, tag [ode](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ode) does not have the synonym [differential-equations](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-equations), which makes it harder to find.

I propose that the tag [differential-equations](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-equations) be created with synonym [ode](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created the tag as a synonym. It can be voted up and put into use now.

Edit: You can vote up the tag here https://economics.stackexchange.com/tags/ode/synonyms

Comment: I don't see the synonym yet. Must another moderator approve it?

Comment: Not sure. You can vote up the tag here https://economics.stackexchange.com/tags/ode/synonyms and I will let the other mods know